# Populating text field in prototype cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

Currently I have a few of custom cell's prototypes created in Storyboard with text fields embedded in them. To access these text fields, I use `nameTextField = cell.viewWithTag:(1)` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. But `viewDidLoad:` and `viewWillAppear:` methods get called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so at that time `nameTextField` is `nil`. To populate text fields when table view shows on screen, I use `viewDidAppear:`, but it results in a noticeable delay. Also, when I scroll table view up and down, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called again and again, resetting already entered data in text fields.

Are there more efficient ways to populate text fields embedded in custom cells' prototypes with data just before the view shows up, and to prevent resetting of entered data in each `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're creating profile screen (or something with many textField to get input data from user). Am I right?

If I'm right, you can use a static tableView (when you have a few textFields)

Hope this can help.

Comment: I agree. Profile screen with static cells is more efficient, so I accept your answer. But I could switch from prototypes to static cells without any problems. That's not always the case. I had to create another view controller with static cells to process text input for other object. Someone may want to process all text input for all objects in one view controller. In that case, static cells aren't an option, because you have to show different text fields for different objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand completely what you're trying to do, but cells are normally configured in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, not in `viewDidLoad`. You can also try connecting the textfield to an outlet on your custom cell class. Then you can do:

```
// in view controller 
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            as! CustomCell

        let object = myDataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.textField.text = object.description
        cell.shouldBecomeFirstResponder = indexPath.row == 0
        return cell
    }

// then in the cell 
    class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var shouldBecomeFirstResponder: Bool = false

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        if shouldBecomeFirstResponder {
            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Then when users input text into the textfield, it would make sense to update your data source.

Comment: Well, my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is written almost exactly as you suggested, but that's not my problem. I have four text fields in four cells. I can populate them with data in the same `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but that's not efficient. Also I can't call `nameTextField.becomeFirstResponder` before the `viewDidAppear` is called, because until that `nameTextField` is `nil`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some logic for making a cell the first responder. The cell's `awakeFromNib` method will be called after all its subviews have been initialized, so there's no risk of getting a `nil` textfield. I'm not sure why it's not efficient to populate cells with data in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Maybe it's interesting in this case, if you have a lot of data, to look at the MVVM pattern. It would mean here that you just pass a data object to the cell, and use that to configure the cell in its own `awakeFromNib` method for example.

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad try to run something like self.tableView.reloadData before you do this line "nameTextField = cell.viewWithTag:(1)".

Comment: Tried it. After `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad` (and also in `viewWillAppear`) the `nameTextField` is still `nil`, so anything like `print(nameTextField)` on the next line results in a crash.